# Command over SSH not running as expected

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

I am trying to send the following command over SSH to all my client servers. My intention is to copy files from /home of the master host to the client servers. The file 'myservers' contains my client servers full qualified hostnames

```
for i in $(cat myservers);do echo;echo "$i";ssh -i id.sshkey root@"$i"; rsync -avzrph --progress -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id.key" root@MASTER_HOST:/home/ /home/;done
```

But the above command fails on my local machine. It does successfully SSH the client host but won't run the rsync part. Kindly share your idea.

Comment: Please don't add tag-like information like "solved" into your question or title. Instead, accept an answer.

Comment: You actually need a configuration management like `ansible`, `chef`, `puppet`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going the rsync route, I'd go with scp instead. As a first step try this

```
scp user1@host1.ext:/dir1/dir2/file.ext user2@host2.ext:/dir2/dir2/dir2/
```

When you confirm operation, you could add compression with -C to increase performance.

When you are happy with this, you can add it to your for loop.

Comment: The use of either rsync or scp is not the problem. The issue is the command exits after SSH'ing the server and rsync or SCP command won't run after that. Do you know how to override it and make sure sequence commands are running after SSH'ing?.

Comment: What I meant was don't use SSH > rsync but only scp instead. With scp you also have the -i <identity file> option. Did you try this?

Comment: As an additional note, from the man page:  scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security as ssh(1).  scp will ask for passwords or passphrases if they are needed for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
for i in $(cat myservers);do echo "";echo "$i";cat rsync.sh | ssh -i id.sshkey root@"$i";done
```

Where rsync.sh contains.

```
➤ cat rsync.sh
#!/bin/bash
rsync -avzrph --progress -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /root/.ssh/id.key' root@MASTER_HOST:/home/ /home/
```